# Are there any security issues in migrating sensitive data in CouchDB to hyperledger composer?

Tags: couchdb, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am thinking of migrating some data in CouchDB to hyperledger composer and expose an api for authentication, are there any security risks involved in this process?

Comment: There are "security issues" with literally everything. To get a useful answer, you'll need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Yes I know, but like if user information like email and password are kept in hyperledgercomposer and exposed through a verification api would be more secure than keeping in couche db? As one of the basic point of blockchain is its better security and everything stored in a ledger.

Comment: The point of blockchain is to be tamper-proof. That's one aspect of security, but does not imply privace in the least. Your question is still too broad.

Comment: I am sorry for that let me try agian, for example data access and exposure can be defined in hyperledger composer through permission file, so based on that system I can give read update or even hide it completely from users with no permissions. So would it be a better idea to store sensitive information there?

Comment: There is no objective answer to that. Security is always a trade-off. The appropriate solution depends entirely on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer and the underlying Hyperledger Fabric will provide certificate based authentication.  Composer and Fabric provide other core such as being Distributed and Immutable.  There are always trade offs.

I would suggest looking at this 2 hour course on [Developer Works](https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/blockchain-essentials/) and then going through the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html)

Both of these resources will go a long way to answering the security question.